# How to remove page numbers behind acronyms?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I would like to remove the page numbers behind my acronyms. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

I create my acronyms the following way:

```
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

...

\begin{document}

    ...

    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
```

Comment: To suppress the page numbers, you can use the `nonumberlist` package option.

Comment: Thank you very much